# How to craft an xpath so it includes not only the full xpath, but also the value in the child element that is referred to

Tags: xml, xpath

I've been trying to get my head around this all day... perhaps you might know the way.

I am trying to craft an XPATH which consists of an explicit and unambiguous xpath and also the data item in the leaf child element referred to.

`/bookstore[3]/book[4]/title` would be a good example of the xpath.

This should return the title of the book number four in bookstore number three. Assume this is good,

However, I want to embed the title in this - and whichever way I try, it seems to go wrong. The purpose is to create an error code in my application which is a valid xpath - and shows the location and value of the offending item.

So, the obvious first try was:

```
/bookstore[3]/book[title="oxford dictionary]/title
```

While this is good, the bookstore has hundreds of oxford dictionaries and I only want number 4.

So I tried many variants such these ... and all fail an online syntax checker.

```
/bookstore[3]/book[[4] and title="oxford dictionary]/title
/bookstore[3]/book[4]/title | /bookstore[3]/book[title=oxford dictionary]/title
```

Any suggestions on how to include an explicit XPATH and tack on the content in the leaf element would be welcome.

Yours sincerely, CR.

Comment: How can you have `/bookstore[3]` when there is only supposed to be one root element?

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the text content in a tag body you can use
   `/bookstore/book[@title="oxford dictionary"][4]/title/text()`
2. To get the text content of an attribute of a tag you can use
   `/bookstore/book[@title="oxford dictionary"][4]/attribute::name`

The first expression will return "Some Text 4" evaluating with the xml bellow.
The second expression will return "title4" evaluating with the xml bellow.

```
<bookstore>
    <book title="oxford dictionary">
        <title name="title1">Some Title 1</title>
    </book>
    <book title="oxford dictionary">
        <title name="title2">Some Title 2</title>
    </book>
    <book title="oxford dictionary">
        <title name="title3">Some Title 3</title>
    </book>
    <book title="oxford dictionary">
        <title name="title4">Some Title 4</title>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```